# Custom radio button property for SharePoint web part

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property, web-part-property

I have created Custom property for string and drop down list .

Currently I'm trying to create radio button custom web part property.

Custom property name will be **City**

2 radio button will be

- Las vegas
- New york

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create Radio Button type property directly as Custom Web part property.

The supported types are:

- Check box
- Text box
- Dropdown

Read more [Creating a Web Part with Custom Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx)

But here is a trick to do that. Because every WebPart Property have radio button in it.

So just overwrite the `GetToolParts()` and prepare your custom.

Detail steps are given at [Create rich web part properties controls using custom tool parts with a complete example code](https://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/create-custom-web-part-properties-using-custom-tool-parts-with-a-complete-example-code/)